# Mockito: mocking an HTTP call with OK HTTP Client

Tags: kotlin, mockito

I'm using Kotlin's OK HTTP Client to make HTTP calls from my application:

```
val httpCall = okHttpClient.newCall(myRequest)
val response = httpCall.execute()
```

The client is created as a bean:

```
@Bean(name = ["okHttpClient"])
fun produceOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient? {
    return OkHttpClient()
}
```

How do I mock this in my unit test using Mockito?

I have a mock bean set up:

```
@Bean
fun okHttpClient(): OkHttpClient? {
    return mock(OkHttpClient::class.java)
}
```

... and I have tried the following in the unit test:

```
val call : Call = mock(Call::class.java)
`when`(okHttpClient?.newCall(any(Request::class.java))).thenReturn(call)
```

... but get this (confusing to me) message when I try and run the test:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: any(Request::class.java) must not be null
```

Comment: `any(Request::class.java)` returns `null` and will always return `null`, and `OkHttpClient` isn't an interface but a concrete class that has an actual behaviour that is not accepting `null` values as arguments. So basically don't mock it, but rather, wrap its behaviour in an interface/concrete implementation and mock that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have moved to using Mockk (https://mockk.io/) instead.